# How to punctuate two sentences that form one unit that requires a colon at the end?

Tags: punctuation, writing-style, colons, tech-writing

I ask this in the context of comments in computer programming which are written in plain English.

For this question, I require a colon at the end of every comment that is a heading of code. **Now, if the heading consists of multiple sentences and I don't want to use a semicolon, is this considered a valid style of punctuation?**

```
# Send e-mail feedback. The user may have opted out:
send()
```

(An answer will also be useful for running text. I came across this issue multiple times over the years.)

EDIT:

Here's a little clue. However, it contains a semicolon:   []

```
Join them; it only takes a minute:
[Join button]
```

Source: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: But is someone going to get on your case for weird punctuation in a source code comment?

Comment: It's a basic question regarding punctuation in the English language.

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Why? It's about the English language, and an answer applies equally to running text; I just have no example for running text. You can also think of the headings as introducing images, which brings us closer to print media.

Comment: "I require a colon at the end of every comment that is a heading of code."  If you've got that requirement then it's up to you to come up with a strategy that suits you.  This is a question about formatting in a computer program, not a question about the English language.

Comment: Sure it is, as my edit proves. I'm not the first one wanting to use a colon above something that is not a direct continuation of the text before. And programming is not the only field in which this question may be raised.

Comment: What makes you think that using multiple sentences, the last one terminating in a colon, is ungrammatical? If any sentence with a colon at the end is ungrammatical, it won't matter how many sentences you have, or whether there is a semicolon somewhere in the middle or not. (A semicolon does not magically make a terminating colon grammatical.) *Send email feedback (the user may have opted out): [send link]*, *As the user may have opted out, send email feedback: [send link]* (I'm not sure if a hyperlink can function as a list item, but I'll assume it can.)

Comment: A colon at the end of the last sentence is good enough for the entire thing. You could write a paragraph or perhaps, a novel even, and end it in a colon signifying that the whole thing "leads to" what follows. Go ahead and have fun, English grammar or writing style has no problem with it.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answers.   @JasonBassford: It's just the notion that a period has a very final character; a semicolon not so much. Multiple sentences ending in a colon, just seems to be something people instinctively avoid--for no good reason, as it appears.

Comment: @Kris: I'll gladly accept this as an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Comment by Kris:

> A colon at the end of the last sentence is good enough for the entire thing. You could write a paragraph or perhaps, a novel even, and end it in a colon signifying that the whole thing "leads to" what follows. Go ahead and have fun, English grammar or writing style has no problem with it.